# What is the difference between given trigonometric functions?

Tags: java, math, trigonometry

In the class java.lang.Math there are several trigonometric methods like sin, sinh, asin, similarly for cosine. I read the descriptions but couldnot able to understand their differences. So please help me on understanding their differences.

Please explain in simple way as I have already read the documentation and could not understand. So I need more simpler language ffrom the documentation.

Comment: What in the descriptions didnt you understand? Do you understand the mathematical functions themselves?

Comment: This isn't really a question about programming - it's a question about basic trigonometry. You should read a maths textbook or something similar.

Comment: Its hard to help, because its not clear what you don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you need some mathematical background, to understand the functions you have listed. The wikipeida is a good start. I really doubt that someone will explain you the trigonometry in a single answer in a way that you will understand.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions - this is for the sine, cosine, arcossine and etc.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_geometry - this is for sinh, cosh and etc.